# Problem with Angular 11 Universal SSR + PWA. Deploying SSR as Cloud Function Functions did not deploy properly

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, progressive-web-apps, server-side-rendering

I want to deploy in Firebase an PWA app developed with Angular 11, using Angular Universal for creating SSR, trying to deploy it as a Firebase-Cloud Function.

Testing in localhost is OK, but when is deployed in Firebase, I get the error: **"Functions did not deploy properly"**, and **"Functions deploy had errors with the following functions: ssr"** with no useful details:

```sh
+  hosting[sample-ssr-pwa]: file upload complete
i  functions: uploading functions in project: ssr(us-central1)
i  functions: creating Node.js 10 function ssr(us-central1)...
!  functions[ssr(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error
cause:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs.
Additional troubleshooting documentation can  be found at
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging.
Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting
for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
       ssr
```

What I have tried:

This is my repo (https://github.com/Sangarllo/ng-sample-ssr-pwa) done with just with 3 steps:

```sh
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
ng add @angular/pwa
ng add @angular/fire (and setting environment with firebase project)
```

and finally, my app.module.ts is:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

With this settings, I test in development mode in localhost (with `ng serve`, `npm run dev:ssr` or `npm run build:ssr + npm run serve:ssr`, and the result is awesome:

[image: Screenshot running in development mode]

But when you develop in firebase (with `ng deploy` command), this is the result:

[image: error when deploying]

I am not sure if the problem is in the way i configure my app.module.ts, becouse when I remove AngularFireModule and AngularFirestoreModule dependences, and deploy, the SSR function is deployed OK, but... firestore feature doesn't work (of course).

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    AppRoutingModule,
    // AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    // AngularFirestoreModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[image: Consele showing deployed OK]
[image: PWA working deployed in Firebase - but without firestore]

Anybody can help me? Is possible to mix Angular + SSR as Cloud Function + PWA + Firebase Hosting?

Comment: have you tried using ` $ firebase emulators:start `  to do a local test of the hosting and functions? it might reveal some things you can't see from a full deploy.

Comment: Are there any logs server side logs? You can check them out by following this [instruction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs).

Comment: Thank you: @BenBradshaw and Rafael. I found the problem (but the logs didn't help my this way). It was needed: 
 1: Use node 12 LTS.
 2: Install [globalThis polyfill](https://github.com/es-shims/globalThis).
After that, I could deploy

Answer (score 3):

you can try changing the functions nodejs version to 12
edit this in the angular.json

```
    "deploy": {
      "builder": "@angular/fire:deploy",
      "options": {
        "functionsNodeVersion": 12,
        "functionsRuntimeOptions": {
          "memory": "1GB",
          "timeoutSeconds": 540
        },
        "ssr": true
      }
    }
```

Comment: With this configuration now my SSR-function is deployed with node 12 (thank you!). But it was not needed to deploy in firebase: I got it just installing node 12 in my PC and using polyfill globalThis